# I am trying to make "Game of Set" but don't know how to correctly check the set

Tags: ruby, algorithm, validation, rubygems, puzzle

Hi so I just started to learn coding and **ruby** is my first language. I am trying to make a game called "Game of Set" the rules can be checked in [here](http://magliery.com/Set/SetRules.html) or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(card_game))

I am able to get users cards and enter them in different arrays. However, I have been spending a lot of time trying to figure out how to validate the set. I tried to compare the arrays index by index but the result is not what I wanted.
Example:

```
first = ['two', 'purple', 'stripe', 'diamond']
second = ['one', 'purple', 'solid', 'diamond']
third = ['three', 'purple', 'empty', 'diamond']
```

this should be correct because all are purple, all are diamond, different number, and different filters.

```
first = ['one', 'green', 'stripe', 'squiggle']
second = ['one', 'purple', 'solid', 'diamond']
third = ['two', 'green', 'empty', 'oval']
```

This is wrong because because two have the same number and one does not, similarly with the color.

This is the game of set that I want to achieve [here](https://www.setgame.com/set/puzzle)

Please help thank you!

Comment: Ruby has a `Set` class (no relation to the game). Add the elements of each column to a `Set`. If the resulting `Set` has either 1 element or 3 elements, then that column is correct.

Comment: I would model the problem in a completely different way: First define a class which represents a **card**. Then create one object of this class for each card which exists in the Deck.  Then define a class, which represents the **location** of the card - this can be one player, the initial deck, or any other relevant part of the table. Initially, all cards are stored in the _deck_ location. To move the card (for instance, from the deck to a player), remove it from its present location and add it to the new location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given

```
first =  ['two',   'purple', 'stripe', 'diamond']
second = ['one',   'purple', 'solid',  'diamond']
third =  ['three', 'purple', 'empty',  'diamond']
```

Let

```
arr = [first, second, third]
  #=> [["two",   "purple", "stripe", "diamond"],
  #    ["one",   "purple", "solid",  "diamond"],
  #    ["three", "purple", "empty",  "diamond"]]
```

We wish to check if every "column" of `arr` contains either the same string for every "row" or a different string in each row.

Ruby doesn't have a concept of array "columns" and "rows", only elements. `arr` has three elements, namely the arrays `first`, `second` and `third`. We can, however, send the method [Array#transpose](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose)<sup>1</sup> to the object `arr` to obtain something we can use:

```
a = arr.transpose
  #=> [["two", "one", "three"],
  #    ["purple", "purple", "purple"],
  #    ["stripe", "solid", "empty"],
  #    ["diamond", "diamond", "diamond"]]
```

We now just have to see if all four elements of `a` pass the test.

For one, we wish to know if

```
b = a[1]
  #=> ["purple", "purple", "purple"]
```

satisfies the required property. A convenient way of doing that is to compute the unique elements of the array `b` with the method [Array#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq):

```
c = b.uniq
  #=> ["purple"]
```

`b` meets the requirement if the number of elements in `c` equals either `1` or the number of elements in `b`, which is `b.size #=> 3`. As `c.size #=> 1`, `c` meets the requirement.

Notice that `b.size` is the same as `arr.size`.

---

We can put this together in a method:

```
def valid?(arr)
  nbr_elements = arr.size
  a = arr.transpose
  a.all? do |b|
    sz = b.uniq.size
    sz == 1 || sz == nbr_elements
  end
end
```

See [Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)<sup>2</sup>

---

Let's try it.

```
valid?(arr)
  #=> true
```

---

To illustrate the calculations performed by `valid?` I will run it again after salting the method with `puts` statements.

```
def valid?(arr)
  nbr_elements = arr.size
  puts "nbr_elements = #{nbr_elements}"
  a = arr.transpose
  a.all? do |b|
    sz = b.uniq.size
    puts "b = #{b}"
    puts "  sz = #{sz}"      
    puts "  #{sz == 1} || #{sz == nbr_elements} => #{sz == 1 || sz == nbr_elements}"
    sz == 1 || sz == nbr_elements
  end
end
```

```
valid?(arr)
  #=> true
```

```
nbr_elements = 3
b = ["two", "one", "three"]
  sz = 3
  false || true => true
b = ["purple", "purple", "purple"]
  sz = 1
  true || false => true
b = ["stripe", "solid", "empty"]
  sz = 3
  false || true => true
b = ["diamond", "diamond", "diamond"]
  sz = 1
  true || false => true
```

---

Let's also try the second example.

```
arr = [["one", "green",  "stripe", "squiggle"],
       ["one", "purple", "solid",  "diamond" ],
       ["two", "green",  "empty",  "oval"    ]]
```

```
valid?(arr)
  #=> false
```

```
nbr_elements = 3
b = ["one", "one", "two"]
  sz = 2
  false || false => false
```

---

In practice we probably would not have the statement `a = arr.transpose` but instead would *chain* `arr.transpose` to `all?`:

```
def valid?(arr)
  nbr_elements = arr.size
  arr.transpose.all? do |b|
    sz = b.uniq.size
    sz.zero? || sz == nbr_elements
  end
end
```

<sup>1 When all elements of an array are arrays having the same number of elements, the methods `transpose` and [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) can be used more-or-less interchangeably. @spickerman has used `zip` in his answer.</sup>

<sup>2 `Enumerable` is a module containing instance methods. Any class that *includes* that module (don't worry about the details now) has use of all of `Enumerable`'s methods, more or less as  though they had been defined in the including class.</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation is very detailed and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

In this game, a __set is defined as:

> Several games can be played with these cards, all involving the concept of a set. A set consists of three cards satisfying all of these conditions:
>
> - They all have the same number or have three different numbers.
> - They all have the same shape or have three different shapes.
> - They all have the same shading or have three different shadings.
> - They all have the same color or have three different colors.
>
> -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(card_game)#Games)

That can be checked with a one-liner:

```
first = ['two', 'purple', 'stripe', 'diamond']
second = ['one', 'purple', 'solid', 'diamond']
third = ['three', 'purple', 'empty', 'diamond']
first.zip(second, third).all? { |array| [1,3].include?(array.uniq.length) }
#=> true

first = ['one', 'green', 'stripe', 'squiggle']
second = ['one', 'purple', 'solid', 'diamond']
third = ['two', 'green', 'empty', 'oval']
first.zip(second, third).all? { |array| [1,3].include?(array.uniq.length) }
#=> false
```

How does this work in detail?

```
first
  .zip(second, third) #=> [["two", "one", "three"], ["purple", "purple", "purple"], ["stripe", "solid", "empty"], ["diamond", "diamond", "diamond"]]
  .all? { |array| 
     # do all nested arrays comply with the set conditions and
     # contain only the same element or three different ones?
    [1,3].include?(array.uniq.length) 
  }
```

Comment: The `.count` part needs to be edited. See @user3386109's comment: "If the resulting `Set` has either 1 element or 3 elements, then that column is correct." In Set (the game), if all the four properties are different for all three cards, that will also count as a valid set.

Comment: @AstridE. Thanks for your comment. I updated my answer to address that issue.

Comment: Great, looks good :)

Comment: thank you! The explanation helps me so much to understand the method uniq and how to use it.